# About floor function - upper estimate

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n$ be positive integers, such that $\left\lfloor \frac{m}{n} \right\rfloor \ge 1$.

It's true that $\left\lfloor \frac{m}{n} \right\rfloor \ge \frac{m}{n+1}$ ?

I searched but didn't find any properties about this.

Comment: what did you try? just write $m = kn + q$, $q < n$

Comment: $\lfloor 5/3\rfloor \not\ge 5/4$

Comment: If $[\frac mn]=k$ then $m=kn+r$ where $0\le r < n$.  So we have to prove or disprove that $k \ge \frac {kn+r}{n+1}$ for all integers $k,n,r$ where $k\ge 1; 0 \le r < n; n>0$.  $k\ge \frac {kn+r}{n+1}\iff ... \iff ....$ what?  [Actually, it's frequently not true.  Let $n=25$ then for $75 \le m \le 99$ we have $[\frac m{25}]=3$.  But $3 \ge \frac {m}{26}$ is only true if $m\le 78$.  So for $79\le m \le 99$.  It's not true.  $3=[\frac {81}{25}] < \frac {81}{25}= 3\frac 3{25}$ for example.

Comment: $\lfloor m/n \rfloor \ge 1 \Longleftrightarrow m \ge n$.